# Taxonomy restricting top navigation to single node

Tags: navigation, taxonomy

I am trying to add top menu items using Taxonomy.

First node gets created, lets say Home
The next one on the top menu is About Us and when I try to add a new node it takes Home as the parent.

I don't want home as the parent, instead it should be on the same level as home.

How can I achieve that.

Am using Taxonomy 3.0.8.3 and EE 2.7.2

Comment: Iain already answered the question in some other forum.

Taxonomy uses the nested set model, so each tree has a single ‘Root’ node, and children from there.
All the output tags have a ‘display_root=“no” parameter so you can emulate level 1 to be your root fairly easily.
Cheers
Iain

Comment: For completion sake you may want to answer your own question as an answer instead of a comment and check it as the accepted answer.